# How to get the index by regular expression in ANT

Tags: regex, string, indexing, ant

I have a string with a version as **.v_september** (every month it will vary). In this i wanted to take the value after underscore, which means **"sep"** (First 3 letters alone).

By using the regex **.v_(.*)** i am able to take the complete month and not able to get the first 3 letters alone.

Can someone help me out how can I achieve this in Apache ANT.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Regex functions on properties are a bit awkward in native Ant (as opposed to working with text within files). Ant-contrib has the `replaceregexp` task, but I try to avoid ant-contrib whenever possible.

Instead, it can be accomplished with the `loadfile` task and a nested filter:

```
    <property name="version" value=".v_september" />

    <loadfile property="version.month.short">
        <propertyresource name="version" />
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="\.v_(.{3}).*" replace="\1" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo message="${version.month.short}" />
```

Regarding the regex pattern, note how it needs to end with `.*`. This is because Ant doesn't have a "match" function that simply returns the content of a capture group. It's just running a replacement, so we need to replace everything in the string that isn't part of the group.

Answer (score 1):

`.*` will capture everything and for limiting to capturing only three characters you need to write `{3}` instead of `*`. Also you should escape the `.` in the beginning of your regex to only match a literal dot. You can use this regex and capture from group1,

```
\.v_(.{3})
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jTnBar/1)**